# Persistent TCP Connections / connection pooling - Amazon CloudFront

Tags: http, tcp, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I’ve seen references to the Persistent TCP Connections / connection pooling capabilities of CloudFront and would like to understand exactly what this means, and how much of a benefit it might offer.

I’m assuming these boil down to the use of HTTP Keep-alives and that the duration of this persistence would be controlled by the origin (e.g. IIS has a default of 2 mins for keep-alive connections)? or is the connection pooling aspect something additional?

Comment: It refers to re-use of the connections between the CDN and origin servers; requests from different users may be sent across the same connection between the CDN and origin.

Comment: @symcbean so Persistent TCP Connections / connection pooling = HTTP Keep-alives? I'm also assuming the connection re-use is CloudFront per-server (not shared amongst CloudFront servers).

Comment: No, Persistent TCP connections = HTTP Keep-alives, the connection pooling is not addressed by the specs for HTTP/1.x

Comment: @symcbean Thanks for the clarification. I'm guessing pooling it's simply a pool of keep-alive connections - and these will last as long as the origin server's default keep-alive timeout setting.